# Topologies on the space $\mathcal D'(U)$ of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

In my analysis lecture I am given a topology on the space of distributions as follows:

Let $u_k$ be a sequence in $\mathcal D'(u)$, $u \in \mathcal D'(u)$. We say $u_k \rightarrow u$, if $\forall \phi \in \mathcal D(u) : u_k(\phi) \rightarrow u(\phi)$.

This is the weak-$*$-topology on $\mathcal D'(u)$. It seems lecturers don't care too much about the topology of $\mathcal D'(u)$, hence I wonder whether there are stronger topologies on $\mathcal D'(u)$.

Comment: For what its worth, I faintly remember from a class about topological vector spaces that the spaces of distributions are nuclear spaces, therefore they cannot be normed spaces (all normed nuclear spaces are finite dimensional).

Comment: I don't think that is technically the weak-$*$-topology, since $\mathcal{D}(U)$ isn't necessarily the dual space of $\mathcal{D}'(U)$.  I think that only holds on bounded domains.

Comment: This is the most common topology on the space of distributions. Schwartz doesn't mention any other one.

Comment: Why do you want to have a stronger topology on $\mathcal D(U)$?

Comment: @JonasTeuwen It seens [Schwartz](https://www.amazon.fr/Th%C3%A9orie-distributions-Laurent-Schwartz/dp/2705655514) mentions two topologies on the space of distributions: the "strong" (p. 71) which is the main topology in the book, and the weak* star (p. 72) which you refer to and plays a secondary role in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly there exist stronger topologies on distributions, but as a practical matter the weak-* definition is the one that is interesting and I assume that was the direction of your question.  There isn't the usual norm topology available on $\mathcal D(U)$, and per Tim's comment do not have a different norm topology either.

$\mathcal D(U)$ is a pretty strict space to be in and to converge in, so it isn't very demanding to be a distribution.  The hard work is all put on the test functions, so to speak.  Although there is a certain amount of interesting things you can do with distributions, practically distributions are a stepping stone for getting to more interesting spaces, such as using their differentiability properties to define Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Some remarks:

$D(U)$ is reflexive, even a [Montel space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel_space), so the dual of $D'(U)$ with weak or strong topology is again $D(U)$ [This is in contrast to Brian's remark].

A linear functional on $D(U)$ is continuous (i.e. a distribution) if and only if it is sequentially continuous. This is remarkable, as the space of test functions $D(U)$ is not metrizable, so sequential continuity is usually *not* sufficient.

A *sequence* of distributions is weakly convergent if and only if it is strongly convergent [i.e. uniformly on bounded subsets of $D(U)$].

The last remark is why usually only the weak topology is known. And Schwartz proved and mentioned this consequence quite often in his book.

Comment: Can you give reference for the second paragraph?

Comment: See my answer I gave in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94897/sequential-and-topological-duals-of-test-function-spaces

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also found Treves' book on TVS explains everything and is very readable.