# Sequential and topological duals of test function spaces

Tags: distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Given a test function space, in particular $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (the [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)) or $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (the space of compactly supported smooth test functions with its usual topology, as defined for instance [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function)), I understand that generalised functions may be defined as elements of the topological dual space, in our examples resp. $\mathcal{S}'$ or $\mathcal{D}'$.

$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a metrisable space, hence sequential.  Therefore its topological dual is the same as its sequential dual, by which I mean the space of sequentially continuous functionals on $\mathcal{S}$.  $\mathcal{D}$, on the other hand, is not metrisable.  I recall having seen somewhere that it is not even first-countable (I would welcome verification).  Nevertheless, I have a vague notion that for a functional $f$ to belong in $\mathcal{D}'$, it is sufficient that it be sequentially continuous on $\mathcal{D}$.  Hence my following questions:

1. Is it true that sequentially continuous functionals on $\mathcal{D}$ are the same as the continuous ones?  Put differently, do the sequential and continuous duals of $\mathcal{D}$ coincide?
2. Assuming 1 is true, does it follow that $\mathcal{D}$—in spite of not being first-countable—is a sequential space?  In other words, do the notions of continuity and sequential continuity coincide for general mappings from $\mathcal{D}$ to an arbitrary topological space $X$?
3. For general test function spaces which may not be sequential, which is more appropriate: To define generalised functions as elements of their continuous dual space, or of the sequential dual?
4. Is 3 even relevant (i.e. can such test function spaces be reasonably conceived), given the many requirements that are normally placed on a test function space, such as nuclearity?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Pouya, unfortunately since MathOverflow is not (yet) a member of the StackExchange 2.0 network, we cannot merge your account there with your one here.

Comment: Would you care to add definitions of $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ as you are using them?  It would make your question more self-contained and eliminate any ambiguity.

Comment: Pouya, for 2. probably you mean $\mathcal{D}$ instead of $\mathcal{D}'$? That's what I assumed in my answer.

Comment: @nate-eldredge, I have linked to the definitions, thanks.

Comment: @Vobo, thanks for the answer, and yes, I did mean $\mathcal{D}$ (corrected).

Comment: Okay, maybe I am stupid, but why is $\mathcal{D}$ not metrizable?  I always sort of assumed in the back of my mind that it was, and if I had to guess at a metric, I'd try $$d(f,g) = \sum_{m,k=0}^\infty 2^{-k-m} \sup_{[-m,m]^n} |f^{(k)} - g^{(k)}|.$$  What am I missing?

Comment: @NateEldredge This is proved for instance in remark 6.9 of Rudin's Functional Analysis.  In brief, $\mathcal{D}$ is sequentially complete (Cauchy sequences converge in it), and can be written as a countable union of subspaces $\mathcal{D}(K_i)$ where $K_i$ are increasing compacts such that $\bigcup K_i =\mathbb{R}^n$.  The latter subspaces are closed and have empty interior in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Baire's category theorem then implies that $\mathcal{D}$ is not metrisable.

Comment: @PouyaTafti: Thanks, I'll look that up.  Maybe I am a candidate for [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics-closed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A first general remark: A topological vector space is metrizable, if and only if it is first countable. To answer your questions:

- Yes, Q1 and Q2 are true. Let $K_i$ be a defining sequence of compact sets for the space $\mathcal{D}$. As the topology on $\mathcal{D}$ is the final topology (i.e. the finest such that all injections $\mathcal{D}_{K_i} \to \mathcal{D}$ are continuous), a map $T$ on $\mathcal{D}$ is continuous, iff its restriction to each $\mathcal{D}_{K_i}$ is continuous. And for this, sequential continuity of $T$ is sufficient (assuming the known fact, that a *sequence* of test functions converges iff the support of the functions are contained in one $K_i$ and the sequence converges in $\mathcal{D}_{K_i}$.
- Q3 and Q4: Don't know if there exist relevant examples. I would always require continuity.

Comment: I believe Q2 is actually false. $\mathcal{D}$ gets its topology from the inductive limit in the _category of locally convex tvs_. The space $\mathcal{D}$ is _not_ sequential. However, sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity when restricted to _linear_ functions. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706061/topologies-of-test-functions-and-distributions#comment1483406_706463).

Comment: @federico Following your links, I see that $\mathcal{D}$ is not sequential. However, sequential continuity and continuity for (not necessarily linear) maps from $\mathcal{D}$ to another toological space conincide.

Comment: @Vobo: That's not true; in this answer (https://mathoverflow.net/a/333618/59219) I construct a function $\Phi : C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is conitnuous when restricted to each space $\mathcal{D}_K$ (and thus sequentially continuous on $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$), but which is not continuous.