# Topologies of test functions and distributions

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I'm wondering about some of the topological properties of $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ and $\mathcal D'(\Omega)$:

1. I know $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ is not metrizable, so not first countable (right?). However, my question is: Is $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ sequential?
2. When $\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ is endowed with the weak* topology, is it sequential? (I presume this one is clearly not first countable either).

How about for $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal S'$?

One of the reasons I ask is that some authors seem to use the theorem:

Given $X$ a sequential space, and $Y$ a topological space, $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is sequentially continuous,

to state that operators of the form $T:\mathcal D'(\Omega)\rightarrow\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ are continuous (like differentiability). However, they never seem to prove or even mention whether $\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ is sequential or not. Are they indeed using the above theorem, some other result, or is this perhaps carelessness?

Comment: Equivalence "metrizable" and "first countable" in the context of locally convex topological spaces is sketched in "Methods of modern mathematical physics I" Reed and Simon (uses semi-norms and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2452641/92038)) or proved differently in "Functional analysis" by Rudin, Thm 1.24 p. 18-19

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not think that $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ is sequential. On the other hand this is probably not used: By definitionn of the locally convex inductive limit topology of $\mathscr D(\Omega)= \lim X_n$ (where $X_n$ are the Frechet spaces of smooth functions with support in $K_n$ for a compact exhaustion) a *linear* map with values in any locally convex space is continuous if (and only if) all the restrictions to $X_n$ are continuous and for this sequential continuity is enough since $X_n$ are metrizable.

Concerning linear maps $\mathscr D'\to \mathscr D'$ like partial differential operators, they are almost always *defined* as transposed maps of continuous operators $\mathscr D\to\mathscr D$ and therefore continuous with respect to the weak* topology.

The situation for $\mathscr S$ and $\mathscr S'$ is simpler because $\mathscr S$ is metrizable.

---

EDIT. $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ fails "very much" to be sequential: There are even linear subspaces which are sequentially closed but not closed (see Klaus Floret, *Some aspects of the theory of locally convex inductive limits* (1980)). Moreover, this is not at all an exotic phenomenon but the hart of the matter when dealing with e.g. linear partial differential operators. If $P:\mathscr D'(\Omega)\to\mathscr D'(\Omega)$ is not surjective but surjective on the space of smooth functions then the range $L$ of its transposed is a closed subspace of $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ such that the relative topology of $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ is different from the inductive limit topology $\lim L\cap X_n$ and these topologies even have different duals. If $u:L\to \mathbb C$ is continuous with respect to the latter but not continuous with respect to the former then its kernel is sequentially closed in $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ (since both topologies have the same convergent sequences) but it is not closed (since otherwise $u$ would be $\mathscr D(\Omega)$-continuous).

Comment: Thanks. This has answered a large part of my question. I'm still curious, especially regarding $\mathcal D(\Omega)$, as to whether these spaces are sequential or not (apart from $\mathcal S$ which is clearly sequential).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation after the edit!

Comment: A final remark, is that indeed both $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ and $\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ are not sequential. The proof of the latter (which was to be expected after seeing your answer) can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-03/S0002-9939-1971-0270145-X/S0002-9939-1971-0270145-X.pdf).